# Redirecting standard input / output to substituted command

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, zsh, io-redirection

I am trying to run a command, which can be simplified to this structure:

```
echo "A,B" | cp $(sed -e 's/A,//') $(sed -e 's/,B//')
```

But I am struggling getting the input / output of the substituted commands right. 
Running the code above yields this error message:
**sed: read error on stdin: Input/output error**

When I run this instead:

```
echo "A,B" | cp <(sed -e 's/A,//') <(sed -e 's/,B//')
```

the command doesn’t terminate.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "A,B" | (IN=$(cat); cp $(echo $IN | sed -e 's/A,//') $(echo $IN | sed -e 's/,B//'))
```

This creates a subshell and saves the stdin input to the `$IN` variable. Then it runs the 2 `sed` commands on the input and uses the outputs for the arguments for `cp`.

Answer (score 2):

Both instances of `sed` are waiting for input on their standard input, which is your terminal. The pipe connects to the standard input of `cp`, not to either of the `sed` instances.

Try this instead:

```
read first second <<< "A,B"
cp "${first}" "${second}"
```

Or, alternatively:

```
var="A,B"
cp "${var%,*}" "${var#*,}"
```

Comment: What I would like to have is a one-liner, doing the following job:
Take output of one command, process it in multiple different ways, and use the results as input parameters for yet another command.

It looks like `sed` is actually getting the input, as:
`echo "123" | echo <$(sed -e 's/2/4/')`
Returns: **zsh: no such file or directory: 143**

Comment: Both process substitutions inherit their standard input from the shell in which `cp` runs, so all three of `cp` and the two `sed` will read from the pipe. `cp` ignores standard input, so it's up to the OS which `sed` gets scheduled to run first and is able to read the incoming string.